# Set Properties location?

Tags: java, properties

I want to set the location of my `Properties` file, but I cannot seem to find a way to do so. Is this possible? I read a few posts about how to find out where it is, but nothing on how to set it.

**Edit**
Guess this needs a bit more detail.

I have a properties file that is created for my project. I only store one or two values but would like to change where this properties file is located.

I have a program that reads and writes a lot of data to a file structure. Something like so:

```
MainDirectory/DirectorywhereIwantPropertiesFile/.properties 
             /OtherNonPropertyData
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if i understand what you want.
Properties can load a file this way:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
File f = new File("Test.properties");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(f);
p.load(reader);
```

If you need a ResourceBundle like this:

```
    ResourceBundle prop = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Test");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, prop.getString("test"));
```

you just have to add the directory with the Test.properties file to your classpath.

Comment: I added an edit. I want to put the properties file in a folder in my program's data area. Let me know if the edit isn't clear